Rational solutions to $\cos(2\pi p)+\cos(2\pi q)+\cos(2\pi r)=0$
Find all solutions to $\cos(2\pi p)+\cos(2\pi q)+\cos(2\pi r)=0$ where $p,q,r\in\mathbb Q$.

I originally got this question from here, which can visually represent a solution $(p,q,r)=\left(\frac rn,\frac gn,\frac bn\right)$ as a point where the red, green, and blue lines intersect, where $n\in\mathbb N$, $3\mid n$, and $r,g,b\in\mathbb Z\cap[0,n-1]$. Note that the fractions need not be reduced, so this can represent any solution $(p,q,r)$.
$(p,q,r)$ being a solution also allows $(-p,q,r)$ and $(1+p,q,r)$ and permutations, so any solution depends on those with $0\le p\le q\le r\le\frac12$. The visualization with its $3\mid n$ and unreduced fractions has additional symmetries: if further assuming $n$ to be even, $\left(\frac rn,\frac gn,\frac bn\right)\implies\left(\frac12-\frac rn,\frac12-\frac bn,\frac12-\frac gn\right)$, $\left(\frac12-\frac bn,\frac12-\frac gn,\frac12-\frac rn\right)$, and $\left(\frac12-\frac gn,\frac12-\frac rn,\frac12-\frac bn\right)$. Up to those and permutation, I visually found 3 kinds of solutions:

The $n$ vertices fit the solutions $\left(p,p+\frac13,p-\frac13\right)$.
When $4\mid n$, the $n-5$ points that form the spokes and center fit the solutions $\left(\frac14,q,\frac12-q\right)$.
When $10\mid n$, the $12$ gold points near the edge fit $\left(\frac16,\frac15,\frac25\right)$, since two of the cosines are the roots of $(2c)^2+(2c)-1$.

As an example, a solution of $\left(\frac6{13},\frac5{39},\frac8{39}\right)$ is not a new kind of solution and can be reduced to $\left(\frac6{13},\frac8{39},\frac5{39}\right)$ or $\left(\frac6{13},1-\frac8{39},-\frac5{39}\right)=\left(\frac6{13},\frac6{13}+\frac13,\frac6{13}-\frac13\right)$ which is a vertex of $n=39$.
The link only computes up to $n=93$. I used this to test up to $n=999$ and have not found a different kind of point. If $\text{lcd}(p,q,r)$ is a factor of any multiple of $3$ up to and including $999$, then the code should rule it out. As a sidenote, Wikipedia cites a source that shows that $\cos\left(2\pi p\right)$ is an algebraic number of degree $\frac12$$\varphi$$(p\text{'s denominator})$. That would mean a new kind of solution will require one of the cosines to have a degree of at least $60$.

Duplicate! I found a 1946 proof by W. J. R. Crosby  that has confirmed the kinds of solutions above to be the only ones.
